# Error using wavread Invalid Wave File. Reason: Cannot open file

Tags: matlab

i got error Error using wavread (line 67)
Invalid Wave File. Reason: Cannot open file.

Error in energy_per_frame (line 2) [inpu fs] = wavread(file);

this is the source code for function that call energy_per_frame.

```
 [inpu fs] = wavread(file);
clc;clear;close all;
file = input('Enter name of wav file  ', 's');
counter=0;
for test_number = 0:4
for test_number2 = 0:20
        counter=counter+1;
        reference = dtw_avg(test_number2);
        test = energy_per_frame(file);
        distance(counter) = dtw(test,reference);
end
```

This is source code for function energy_per_frame

```
 [inpu fs] = wavread(file);
    fn = fs/2;
bins = 512; %useable bins
frame_length = bins;
window = hamming(frame_length);
overlap = .5;
number_of_frames = (length(inpu)/(frame_length)/overlap) - 1;
```

What is wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

Well, your function definition should look something like this

```
function [ output_args ] = energy_per_frame( input_args )
%UNTITLED Summary of this function goes here
%   Detailed explanation goes here


end
```

It looks like your missing the `function` keyword.

However, if the first block is just supposed to be a script then you're making the call to wavread before you actually have the user input for the filename.  Also, there is really no need to call clear etc. like that in a function.

Comment: I think there are the problem at for test_Number2=0:20, If I change it to 1:4, there are no such error. But I want it to sample more.

Comment: That's another issue with your code I didn't notice.  In Matlab there are no 0 indices.  The index of the first element is always 1.  any expression like x(0) will always give an error when x is a matrix.